# How to bypass Authentication in Latest JBPM 7.62

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management, kie, drools-kie-server, kie-server

I have configured latest version of JBPM which is 7.62, previously I was using 7.58v and I have successfully achieve that how can I bypass user and how I can Claim, Start and Complete any task with any user by using this property which set in standalone.xml file

```
<property name="org.kie.server.bypass.auth.user" value="true"/>
```

but in this new version I received below error

[image]

why this above property not working on new version of JBPM can anyone please help me here.

TIA

Server Log:

```
WARN  [org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor] (default task-8) Could not commit session: org.jbpm.services.task.exception.PermissionDeniedException: User '[UserImpl:'qa']' does not have permissions to execute operation 'Claim' on task id 2821
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.internals.lifecycle.MVELLifeCycleManager.evalCommand(MVELLifeCycleManager.java:127)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.internals.lifecycle.MVELLifeCycleManager.taskOperation(MVELLifeCycleManager.java:392)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.impl.TaskInstanceServiceImpl.claim(TaskInstanceServiceImpl.java:157)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.commands.ClaimTaskCommand.execute(ClaimTaskCommand.java:52)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.commands.ClaimTaskCommand.execute(ClaimTaskCommand.java:33)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl$SelfExecutionCommandService.execute(TaskCommandExecutorImpl.java:80)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl$SelfExecutionCommandService.execute(TaskCommandExecutorImpl.java:65)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor.execute(TaskTransactionInterceptor.java:88)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor.execute(TaskTransactionInterceptor.java:49)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jta.TransactionLockInterceptor.execute(TransactionLockInterceptor.java:73)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jta.TransactionLockInterceptor.execute(TransactionLockInterceptor.java:45)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.internalExecute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:102)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.execute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:83)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.execute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:44)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.error.ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.internalExecute(ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.java:66)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.error.ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.execute(ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.java:52)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.error.ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.execute(ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.java:29)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.runtime.InternalLocalRunner.execute(InternalLocalRunner.java:37)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.runtime.InternalLocalRunner.execute(InternalLocalRunner.java:41)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl.execute(TaskCommandExecutorImpl.java:49)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.impl.command.CommandBasedTaskService.claim(CommandBasedTaskService.java:167)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.task.SynchronizedTaskService.claim(SynchronizedTaskService.java:104)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.UserTaskServiceImpl.claim(UserTaskServiceImpl.java:190)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.kie.server.services.jbpm.UserTaskServiceBase.claim(UserTaskServiceBase.java:93)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.kie.server.remote.rest.jbpm.UserTaskResource.claim(UserTaskResource.java:197)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:546)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:435)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:396)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:398)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:338)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.9.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.9.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.9.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0):

This indicated that "qa" user is not allowed to work on that task. That means it is not potential owner not business admin of the task. Try evaluation process and assign "qa" as the employee and you should be able to interact with tasks. Please check server log if any caused or warn messages there.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. 

Actually, In my case I want to assign a task to any user and for this I have used the above mentioned property.

Yes, you're right **qa** is not a potential owner of the task but I want to assign that task to 'qa' and I also don't want to add this user in JBPM. 

Why this error is coming if I have by pass the authentication? and Why this is happening in latest version ?

P.S. Server Log added.

Comment: Please go through the article https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/09/22/troubleshooting-user-task-errors-in-red-hat-process-automation-manager-and-red-hat-jboss-bpm-suite#simplifying_user_task_access_control    and read it from section Simplifying user task access control till end.